# How can I use activerecord's query interface and scopes to identify the favorite in a race

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models Starter and Race.

```
Starter    belongs_to :race
Race       has_many :starters
```

The attributes for Starter and race follow:

```
Starter attributes:  id, race_id, finish_position, odds
Race: id, race_date, race_number, field_size
```

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

1. Select the **favorite** in each race.  *#for a particular race the Starter with the lowest odds**
2. Select any **beaten favorites**  *#a favorite that has a finish_position > 1*

The logic for determining favorites and beaten favorites is pretty straight forward (see above), but I'm having a hard time translating the logic into activerecord also is this an example were activerecord scopes could be utilized.

Here's my attempt at favorite:

Starter.joins(:race).where(:finish_position => minimum(finish_position))

This isn't working, but I still working at it.

I guess the ideal would be to have a favorite scope and a beaten scope.

Answer (score 1):

For favorites, you can use this

```
favorites = Starter.group(:race_id).having('min(odds)')
```

For beaten favorites

```
beaten_favorites = favorites.where(['finish_position > ?', 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some principles at first:

1. The "favorite" and "bean_favorites" only make sense when a race exists. So they are better to be instance methods instead of class methods.
2. Your race should know **no more than one level** of Starter's methods, according Single Responsibility Principle

Now comes the code

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  def favorite
    starters.lowest_odds
  end

  def beaten_favorite
    starters.finished_lowest_odds
  end
end

class Starter < ActiveRecords::Base
  scope :by_odds, order('odds DESC')
  scope :finished, where('finished_position > 1')

  def lowest_odds
    by_odds.last
  end

  def finished_lowest_odds
    finished.lowest_odds
  end
end
```

Now to solve the question

```
@race.favorite
@race.beaten_favorite
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your principles were quite helpful.  If I planned to do something like use the scope or class method across associations would it then make sense to set favorite and beaten_favorite as class methods or scopes.  For example, Race.joins(:starters).merge(Starter.favorite).  This is something I picked up from Railscasts 215.