# Drop down list box for a field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i don't know how to do this. I just want to have a drop down list box for a field instead of text field.I want to show a drop down list for country column of Profile model...any help will be appreciable

Comment: Have a look at [this][1]. Its pretty simple to be explained here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772766/how-can-i-use-activerecords-query-interface-and-scopes-to-identify-the-favorite

Comment: thanks for your answer.but this is not what i am looking for..i want to have a drop down list box for a field.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constant in your model:

```
COUNTRIES = ["Democratic", "Republic"]
```

Then, in the view, create a dropdown list in your form and use the constant to populate it.

Something like this:

```
= f.select :country, ModelName::COUNTRIES, { prompt: "Select Country" }
```